# how to handle the error in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is a piece of an existing dojo based project

```
    nps.makeRequest = function(args) {
    //add some default params          
    return dojo.xhr("POST", args, true); // dojo/_base/Deferred
    };
```

The issue is if the respose has an error message(text message) it is displayed properly.
if the response is say 404 and if there is a custom error page served , it will display the HTML source code of 404 page instead of interpreting it.
how to handle the error here?

Comment: The promises returned by Dojo's XHR functions typically reject on error status codes, so what you are describing does not match the normal behavior.  Are you sure your server isn't clobbering the HTTP status code for those 404s when the custom error page is involved?  Can you show an example of how you are handling the returned promise?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```
args = {
    url: 'http://...',
    error: function() { /* this handles error*/ }
};
nps.makeRequest(args);
```

Or you can use the deferred:

```
nps.makeRequest({url: 'foo'}).then(function() { /* this handles happy flow*/ }, function() { /* this handles error*/ });
```